# Select From Query where the user id is causing errors

Tags: php

I'm really confused as to what number should be within the query where I aim to match the user. Originally I had usersid=1"; but my teacher wanted me to change the number to 0 I did this and now I just receive errors does the number have to equal to 0 or am i missing a piece of code.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM login WHERE usersid=0";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $r["firstname"];
    echo " ";
    $usersid=$r["usersid"];
    echo "<br>";
```

Comment: I doubt ID's start at `0` it' been known to cause havoc having an id as zero. Your teacher has thrown you what we call a *curve ball* ;-) You have to figure out the "why".

Comment: Do you have a row in your table where userid=0?

Comment: brother seriously you need to learn a lot? read basic sql,php tutorials.

Comment: so is it best to stick to 1

Comment: Yes, start from `1` and if your column is set to AUTO_INCREMENT, any new entries will be `2`... `3`... etc. Plus, you can get rid of the `WHERE usersid=0` altogether; it will still show your column entries. If you want to show a column from a particular person's name, then use `WHERE firstname='Larry'`

Comment: There are some situations where it'll not start from 1 so it's not good practice to write apps that way.

Comment: This is a prime example of why you should put the output, including the error, of your program in the post too.  We don't know exactly what's going on.  In fact, the output of "EXPLAIN login;" wouldn't be bad either so we can see the table schema.

Comment: this is the error    Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/mediaedi/public_html/roxanne/userpage.php on line 69
nothing found

Comment: That means your query is incorrect check fred ii comment below

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you have hit any rows before you try to echo it.

```
   $query="SELECT * FROM login WHERE usersid=0";                                                                                                                                                               
                    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {                                                            
                    $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    echo $r["firstname"];                                                                                                                                           
                    echo " ";                                                                       
                    $usersid=$r["usersid"];                                                                     
                    echo "<br>";
    }
    else 
    {
      echo "nothing found";
    }
```

Comment: the query is coming out with errors it doesn't like the numbers used i changed to 1 and still have the same error

Comment: @user3414573 If your column isn't an `int` then try wrapping it in quotes. I.e.: `usersid='1'` Plus, make sure you mean `usersid` and not `userid` you may have made a typo in your column; it happens.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/mediaedi/public_html/roxanne/userpage.php on line 69
nothing found    I've tried wrapping them in quotes but it is still an issue

Comment: just to be sure do you have a connection to your database?

Comment: yes i do the connection works on all of my other php pages so i know that is not the issue

Comment: It doesn't proof you have on this one.

Comment: include "conninfo.php"; this is set at the top of the page

Comment: it's not best place to chat here to solve some sort of simple issue doing it pasting one line after another. You have to give more details and descriptions in the main question. The code, what you tried, what are error messages, warnings etc.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get user with lowest `userid` from the `login` table then use:

`SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY usersid LIMIT 1`

A few others things that your teacher should tell you are:

1. `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will be removed so you should use `mysqli_` instead which is similar to use or PDO - much more advanced and powerfull but at the same time will save you some effort when you take care of propper variables escaping to prevent SQL injection attacks on your app.
2. do some error handling in your app

Comment: any reason for -1 here ? Fred -ii- ?

Comment: The few other things are useful, but you don't address the posters problem at all is my guess.

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM login WHERE usersid=1";  
if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 1)
    {

Comment: the num rows is being an issue

Comment: Looking at her code I suppose she wants to get only one record for the very first user.

Comment: There is a `where` clause, which narrows it down to one row already. There is no need for `limit`.

Comment: This is the point to use LIMIT 1 instead of WHERE. Is it so difficult to understand what "if you want to get user with lowest userid" means ??